# How to write the following query correctly?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Find all bars that sell beers that are cheaper than all beers sold by "99 bottles"

EDIT:

Interpretation:
So compare all the beers from Bar1 and check if all the those beers are cheaper than "99 bottles"

example:

```
     Is bluemoon price in motiv cheaper than bluemoon in 99 bottles?
     Is Guiness price in motiv cheaper than Guiness in 99 bottles?
```

Since there is only two beers in each bar. Then motiv has cheaper beer.

This is what I have so far but I do not get the right output.

```
select * from sells s1, sells s2 where s1.bar <>s2.bar and s2.bar <> 
'"99 bottles"' and s1.beer=s2.beer and s1.price < all 
(select s.price from sells s where s.bar ='"99 bottles"') ;
```

The following is what the table contains.

```
     bar      |   beer   | price 
--------------+----------+-------
 "99 bottles" | Bluemoon |    10
 "99 bottles" | Guiness  |     9
 "rosies"     | Bluemoon |    11
 "rosies"     | Guiness  |     5
 "motiv"      | Bluemoon |     4
 "motiv"      | Guiness  |     2
```

The solution should be motiv, but I am having trouble trying to get the right query.

Comment: what is yor expected output for this above..table

Comment: The solution should be motiv. the name of the bar. As I've stated above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.bar
FROM barbeerprice b
WHERE b.bar <> '99 bottles'
        -- '99 bottles' must not sell a same beer cheaper
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM barbeerprice me
        JOIN barbeerprice nx99
                         ON nx99.beer = b.beer
                        AND nx99.bar = '99 bottles'
                        AND nx99.bar <> me.bar
                        AND nx99.price < me.price
        WHERE me.bar = b.bar
        )
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need the beers cheaper than cheapest beer in 99 bottles. Try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM sells s1
where s1.price < (select MIN(price) FROM sells s2 where s2.bar = '"99 bottles"') and s1.bar <> '"99 bottles"'
```

PS: if you want show just the bar with ALL beer cheaper than 99 bottles, this query need some edit.

Comment: I've made an edit to further explain what the query should output. I've also try that, but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

- the `DISTINCT` keyword to prevent the same bar from being listed multiple times if it has multiple beers that meet the criterion
- a `WHERE` clause with a subquery that uses the `MIN()` function to find the lowest price for that bar

As follows:

```
select distinc bar
from sellsy
where price < (
    select min(price)
    from sells
    where bar = '"99 bottles"')
```

---

To compare beer by beer, the question would be:

> Find all bars whose prices are cheaper than "99 bottles"

and the query would be:

```
select s2.bar
from sells s1
join sells s2
    ob s1.beer = s2.beer
    and s2.price < s1.price
where s1.bar = '"99 bottles"'
group by 1
having count(s2.beer) = count(s1.beer)
```

Note the elegant way that the "all beers" criterion is asserted via the HAVING cluase. This still allows for the bar the sell *other* beers that 99 bottles don't sell.

Also, just a side note - it is steange to have wrapping quotes saved in names.

Comment: This only gives the cheapest beer they sold which is not the questions asks. What place sell the cheapest beer by comparing each beer. As stated in the question above.

Comment: This acrually does answer the original question perfectly. I think you'd interpretation us wrong. This is clearly homework/classwork, so better ask your teacher exactly what (s)he means.

Comment: I apologize if the questions was misunderstood, but like I've stated before I wanted to find which bars sell cheaper beer than 99 bottles. I wanted to compare the beers one by one. So something like this `While(list of beer){if bar1.beer==bar1.beer && bar2.name="99 bottles && bar1.price<bar2.price & bar1.bar!=bar2.bar then add to result list`

Comment: See edit to my answer for an elegant solution to your question. I think it should work - I haven't do e a query like that before. Let me know if it works please.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will find all beers that are equally or more expensive as compared to beers sold in "99 bottles":

```
select * from beers join beers compare on ( 
    beers.beer = compare.beer and beers.price >= compare.price
) where compare.bar = '99 bottles';
```

The result is as follows:

```
bar;beer;price;bar;beer;price
"99 bottles";"Bluemoon";10;"99 bottles";"Bluemoon";10
"99 bottles";"Guiness";9;"99 bottles";"Guiness";9
"rosies";"Bluemoon";11;"99 bottles";"Bluemoon";10
```

this query can be easily used to find all bars which have lower prices on all beers, we need to find all bars which arent present on the above list:

```
select distinct bar from beers where bar not in (
    select beers.bar from beers join beers compare on ( 
            beers.beer = compare.beer and beers.price >= compare.price
        ) where compare.bar = '99 bottles'
);
```

The result is:

```
bar
"motiv"
```

I hope that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use "Group By" With "Having clause".

Answer (score 0):

Check the below query. This should solve your purpose

```
Declare @sells table(Bar varchar(100),brand varchar(100),price int)
insert into @sells
select '99 bottles','Bluemoon',10
union all
select '99 bottles','Guiness',9
union all
select '99 bottles','KF',9
union all
select 'rosies','Bluemoon',11
union all
select 'rosies','Guiness',5
union all
select 'motiv','Bluemoon',4
union all
select 'motiv','Guiness',2

;with cteBar
as
(
select s1.price as actualprice,s2.* from @sells as s1 right outer join 
@sells as s2 on(s1.brand=s2.brand and s1.price>s2.price and s1.Bar='99 bottles')
)

select Bar from cteBar group by Bar having count(actualprice)=count(price)
```

The result is motiv as you expected.